# Return variable columns from p/sql function/procudre

Tags: plsql

I am trying to write a pipeline function whose return columns are not fixed.
some time it may return 1 column, sometime 2, with maximum of 10 columns can be returned.
is there a way in Pl/sql we can achieve this?

Comment: It's not going to be straightforward. You can probably do it by having the pipelined function return [`anydataset`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/t_anyset.htm), something like [this article](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=422).

Comment: what is the input to this function.. Is it a sql query as a input

Comment: sounds like you might really want a sys_REFCURSOR.. not a pipelined function.